# Did not find any initialized language workers error getting in dot net 5 isolated Linux function app

Tags: azure-functions

I have multiple environments on Azure, two as Windows consumption plan, one as Linux App Service plan, same code deployed.

Two environments with Windows consumption plan work correctly, Linux App Service plan shows this error: "Did not find any initialized language workers". Same code deployed. Of course I have set all the Configs as FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue and resolved using the following steps:

1. Created the **Windows Consumption Plan Function App** (Stack: .Net Core 6) and **Linux App Service Plan Function App** in Azure.
2. Created the **.Net 5 Isolated Azure Function App** in Visual Studio and did run locally

[image]

3. Published this function app to **Windows Consumption Plan Function App** where it is asked to change the version in Azure automatically > clicked yes and started publishing.
   After publishing, run the function using function URL:

[image]
[image]

4. In the publish window of Visual Studio Project, deleted the published profile like below:

[image]
[image]

5. Same Code Published to **Azure Linux Function App** from Visual Studio and it is running well:

[image]

[image]